# cancel edit in wpf for datepicker

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

```
<DataGrid Name="Tst"  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="RecordDate">
               <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                         <DatePicker Text="{Binding RecordDate}" />
                     </DataTemplate>
               </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn>            
     </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

i have a button Enable edit . the datepicker need to be enable only if the button is pressed; else the editing should be disable

Comment: Then why make it editable in the first place?

Comment: i have a button Enable edit . the datepicker need to be enable only if the button is pressed; else the editing should be disable

Comment: Then bind the IsReadOnly property of the DatePickerTextBox, or the IsEnabled property of the DatePicker, to a source property and implement the INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the `DatePickerTextBox` read-only:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="RecordDate">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DatePicker Text="{Binding RecordDate}">
                <DatePicker.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
                        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
                    </Style>
                </DatePicker.Resources>
            </DatePicker>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```